# Can't reach function inside controler from view

Tags: javascript, extjs, model-view-controller, touch

I can't seem to reach the function inside a controller from my view. It seems I'm missing something but i do not know what. I can reach it using the non-sencha way but that leaves me with not consistant code in the future. Could some one spot the error and explain why it is going wrong.

Thank you for looking at my code.

```
Ext.define('imp.view.Test', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    alias: "widget.test",
    xtype: 'test',
    controllers: 'imp.controller.Test',
    requires: [ 'imp.util.Utility'
             , 'imp.controller.Test'],

    config: {
        title:'Test',
        scrollable: null,
        items: [

            {
                xtype: 'button',
                itemId: 'postButton',
                ui: 'action',
                padding: '10px',
                text: 'Post'
            }]


    }



});
```

controller:

```
Ext.define('imp.controller.Test', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    config: {
        refs: {
            testView: 'test'
        },
        control: {
            'test #postButton': {
                tap: 'onPostCommand'
            }
        }
    },

        onPostCommand: function (){
            console.log('klik');


        }

    }
);
```

Comment: I have updated my code. Still have no clue why it is not working..

Answer (score 0):

I think there are multiple ways of doing this. I always write my controllers like this:

```
Ext.define('imp.controller.Login', {
  extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
  init: function(){
    this.control({
      'button[action=test_command]' :   {click:this.test_cmd},
    });
  },
  test_cmd: function(){
    console.log("test command pressed!");
  }
});
```

With this strategy, your button would need a config

```
action: "test_command"
```

and you could remove the id of the button and listener declaration you have. I'm not quite sure what the onTestButtonTap function at the bottom of your view file is supposed to do. Did you mean to have two separate functions?

Comment: Just following the Sencha way of doing this. The onTestButtonTap function has to fire the event form the controller.

Comment: well if by "Sencha way" you mean following MVC then  my way does as well. The button action connects to a listener in the controller. If you look at the controller documentation you can see they also initialize the connection to views in the init function: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/5.0.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.app.Controller

Answer (score 0):

View:

```
Ext.define('imp.view.Login', {
extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
alias: "widget.login",
xtype: 'login',
requires: ['Ext.form.FieldSet',
    'Ext.form.Password',
    'Ext.Label',
    'Ext.Img',
    'Ext.util.DelayedTask',
    'imp.controller.Login'],

config: {

    title: 'Login',

    items: [


        {
            xtype: 'button',
            itemId: 'testButton',
            ui: 'action',
            padding: '10px',
            text: 'Test',
            handler: function(btn) {
              var view= btn.up('login');
              view.fireEvent('testCommand', view);
            }
        }
    ]

}
});
```

Controller:

```
Ext.define('imp.controller.Login', {
extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
config: {
    refs: {
        loginView: 'loginview',
        mainMenuView: 'mainmenuview'
    }
},

init: function () {
    this.control({
        'login': {
            testCommand: this.onTestCommand,
         }
    })
},

onTestCommand: function (){
    console.log('onTestCommand');

}});
```

Comment: I dont understand why you create a function in the view to call a function in the controller, doesnt that take away from the power of MVC? With my solution all the function logic goes in the controller by binding the controller function to the action config

Comment: @alex9311, just another way of handling events. With this you can create your own events. F.e., when you need custom event depending on state of view. View fires the event and each controller using same view will decide handle it or not.

Comment: I see, so by custom events do you mean mostly being able to pass whatever parameters you want?

Comment: yes, + firing whenever you want(f.e. when two textfields are both blank), and name your event whatever you want

Answer (score 0):

This is the standard way:
No logic in UI, I removed all of event-related codes

```
Ext.define('imp.view.Login', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    alias: "widget.login",
    xtype: 'login',
    requires: ['Ext.form.FieldSet',
        'Ext.form.Password',
        'Ext.Label',
        'Ext.Img',
        'Ext.util.DelayedTask',
        'imp.controller.Login'],

    config: {
        title: 'Login',
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'button',
                itemId: 'testButton',
                ui: 'action',
                padding: '10px',
                text: 'Test'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                itemid: 'editBox'

            }
        ]

    }
});
```

Here how to handle the Tap even in a controller:

```
Ext.define('imp.controller.Login', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    config: {
        refs: {
            loginView: 'loginview',
            mainMenuView: 'mainmenuview'
        },
        control: {
            'loginview #testButton': {
                tap: 'onTestCommand'
            }
        }
    },

    onTestCommand: function (button, e, eOpts){
        console.log('onTestCommand');
        /*a sefe way to get editbox value*/
        var Form = button.up('formpanel');
        var editbox = Form.down('#editBox');
        var value = editbox.getValue();

    }});
```

Comment: This seems to be the way i expect it to work.. I'll try this. But one more thing if i have a textfield in the views and i want to use it's value in the controller, what is the way of getting that value.

Comment: @Robert I updated the answer. The are several way to get values I think this is the standard way.

Answer (score 0):

You catch the events in the controller, the view should only contain UI markup.

In my experience, the controller should look like this:

```
Ext.define('imp.controller.Login', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    //....
    views: ['imp.view.Login'],
    init: function(){
        this.control({
           'button': {
               click: this.handleButtonClick
           }
    },
    handleButtonClick: function (button) {
        switch (button.itemId) {
            case 'testButton':
                this.testButtonClick();
                break;
        }
    },
    testButtonClick: function () {
        console.log('Clicked');
    }
});
```